# d3 v4 TypeScript types

Tags: d3.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm putting together a little d3 project and since it's quite complex, I wanted to use TypeScript to make some of the development a bit simpler and less error-prone.

I'm using d3 v4. I think I was using the wrong type definition file before, but I didn't run into any problems for a long time until it eventually complained that `d3` does not contain a definition for `scaleLinear()`.

I've since moved to what I believe is the correct definition file, which *does* have a definition for `d3.scaleLinear()`, however now a significant number of my variables have invalid types.

Here are some examples:

```
public SVGElement    : d3.Selection<SVGElement>;
public SVGTitleArea  : d3.Selection<SVGGElement>;
public SVGLegendArea : d3.Selection<SVGGElement>;
public SVGXAxisArea  : d3.Selection<SVGGElement>;
public SVGYAxisArea  : d3.Selection<SVGGElement>;
public SVGChartArea  : d3.Selection<SVGGElement>;
```

I used to create these like this:

```
this.SVGElement = d3.Select("body").append("svg");
this.SVGTitleArea = <d3.Selection<SVGGElement>>this.SVGElement.append("g");
```

etc.

I also have a number of functions that render different components of the graph:

```
public RenderTitle() : d3.Selection<SVGGElement> {
  this.SVGTitleArea = <d3.Selection<SVGGElement>>this.SVGElement.append("g");

  // Do stuff here

  return this.SVGTitleArea;
}
```

Ever since moving to the probably-correct typings file, it now complains that the `d3.Selection` type expects 4 types:

```
interface Selection<GElement extends Element | EnterElement | Window, Datum, PElement extends Element | EnterElement | Window, PDatum>
```

Now, I know it's not ideal and I would prefer a stronger typing, but I've managed to at least fix the errors with respect to the variable definitions:

```
public SVGElement    : d3.Selection<SVGElement, any, any, any>;
public SVGTitleArea  : d3.Selection<SVGGElement, any, any, any>;
public SVGLegendArea : d3.Selection<SVGGElement, any, any, any>;
public SVGXAxisArea  : d3.Selection<SVGGElement, any, any, any>;
public SVGYAxisArea  : d3.Selection<SVGGElement, any, any, any>;
public SVGChartArea  : d3.Selection<SVGGElement, any, any, any>;
```

But I can't do the same for the render functions:

```
public RenderTitle() : d3.Selection<SVGGElement, any, any, any>
```

I've tried hovering over the calls that create, for example, the `<g>` element to see exactly what the signature should be, but it actually gives the `, any any any>`.

What is my best option here? Is there a simple way to fix these types? Should I just leave them all as `any`? Should I downgrade to d3 v3? Should I keep using v4 and abandon TypeScript?

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Exactly where your problem is I do not see. This is possible:

```
let mySelection : d3.Selection<SVGElement, {}, HTMLElement, any> = d3.selectAll<SVGElement, {}>('#line');
function foo() : d3.Selection<SVGElement, {}, HTMLElement, any> {
  return mySelection.append<SVGElement>('g')
}
alert(foo().node().tagName)
```

Comment: Thanks. (1) I had the wrong template signature for the `Selection` variable definitions, and (2) I didn't realise you could assign specific types to the function calls, such as `gObj = mySelection.append<SVGGElement>("g")`; I was instead trying to cast the whole assignment: `gObj = <d3.Selection<SVGGElement, /*something*/, /*something*/, /*something*/>>mySelection.append("g")`. Thank you, your suggestions seem to work.